# CouchDB init.d script for Trusty

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, couchdb

I have installed CouchDB 1.6.1 on a Trusty box via the Apache CouchDB PPA (`couchdb/stable`). This all seems to work, except that I cannot start the service using `service couchdb start` (similarly for stop). I've got around this by putting the following script in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ERL_FLAGS="+A 16"
export ERL_MAX_PORTS=8192
nohup couchdb > /opt/couchdb/log/couch.log 2>&1 &
```

I have to run this manually (or stop it with `kill`). The `service` commands say they work, but CouchDB just immediately fails. This is fine, except in the rare event that the machine needs rebooting; it would be nice if CouchDB came up automatically.

On various pages I've found online, there is reference to a bundled `init.d` script. In fact, I found a [generated `init.d` script](https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/b50d7c88b8421eda0ae6), which is supposed to be installed along with CouchDB: I tried this, edited appropriately, but the same problem persists.

It seems a lot of the documentation I've found online is very out-of-date (e.g., it references paths that are not valid with the PPA installed version and/or Trusty). What is the current "best way to do this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason starting/stopping CouchDB with Upstart was failing was because the directory it wanted to write to (logs, data, etc.) -- which was different from the installed default -- was not accessible to the `couchdb:couchdb` user. That is, the following fixed the problem:

```
chown -R couchdb:couchdb /path/to/couchdb
```

I found this out almost by accident. Obviously as it couldn't write to the logfile it wanted, that was useless. However, the Upstart logs gave a better indication of what had gone wrong!

Anyway, as such, the `init.d` script is an irrelevant red herring. It works as documented, provided it can access everything it needs.